# Setting x axis labels position with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis-labels

I have a problem setting the x axis for a simple visualization made with D3.js.
I have something like the following image:
[image]

Obtained with this code (taken from an example I'm following):

```
    var start_year = 2006, end_year = 2015;

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top");

    var formatYears = d3.format("0000");
    xAxis.tickFormat(formatYears);

    var svg = d3.select("#page_content").append("svg")
            .attr("width", "100%")
            .attr("height", "100%")
            .style("margin-left", 0)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    x.domain([start_year, end_year]);

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([start_year, end_year])
            .range([0, width]);

    var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 0 + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
```

The problem is that I'm dealing with football seasons, so I would like to have for the x axis domain something like "2006/2007", "2007/2008" and so on.

I tried by creating an array of strings and using it as x domain:

```
    domain_data = ["2006-2007","2007-2008","2008-2009","2009-2010","2010-2011","2011-2012","2012-2013","2013-2014","2014-2015","2015-2016"];

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top");

    var svg = d3.select("#page_content").append("svg")
            .attr("width", "100%")
            .attr("height", "100%")
            .style("margin-left", 0)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    x.domain(domain_data.map(function(d) { return d; }));

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([start_year, end_year])
            .range([0, width]);

    var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 0 + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
```

but, as you can see from the following image, each label is slightly shifted on the right or on the left with respect to the circles.
[image: With an array of strings as domain]

I'm very new to D3.js so if someone can explain me how to fix this problem, or maybe a better solution to achieve my goal, it'll be very helpful. Thanks in advance

** *** EDIT: Added a JSFiddle *** **

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/ne1ozr9n/26/) is the JSFiddle you asked, hope it helps finding the solution. Thank you

Comment: Can you add a working example (JSFiddle or similar) of your code?

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle or at least the demo link ? So we can build it ourselves...

Comment: I added a link to the JSFiddle.